# Como fazer arredondamento para cima com Python?

Tags: python, matemática

Existe algum modo nativo do Python para arrendondar para cima?

**Exemplo:** `10/3` tendo como resultado `4`.

O que estou usando agora é uma condicional:

```
x=10  
if x % 3 != 0:  
    x += 1
```

Mas assim não é muito prático.

Comment: No *Python3* a divisão retorna um valor `float`, com isso é possível arredondar pro valor mais acima usando o método *built-in* `round()` (e.g `round(3/2)  = 1.5`, logo fica `2`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usando pura matemática sempre que quiser arredondar um número para cima adicione uma unidade inteira do valor que quer que seja feito o arredondamento e pegue a parte inteira, isto garantirá que sempre cairá no próximo valor. Mas tem um problema que a pergunta trata, quando já for inteiro não pode fazer a soma, então não tem como escapar disso:

```
x = x + (1 if x % int(x) else 0)
```

Se desejar pode usar uma função pronta do Python que é o [`ceil()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil) que faz bater no teto:

```
x = ceil(x)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Math/Rounding.py).

Mas note que isso tem alguns critérios, e eles podem até serem mais adequados se os entender. Pode dar resultado diferente se é negativo ou positivo.

No fundo a função fará essas verificações para você, não é que está fazendo menos, apenas está abstraindo para você.

Answer (score 5):

Tente usar a função [`math.ceil()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html).

```
x = 10
x= x % 3
x = ceil(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Estava com a mesma dúvida e cai aqui de paraquedas , a respeito do código acima:

```
x = x + (1 if x % int(x) else 0)
```

Esse caso funciona muito bem na maioria dos casos , porém quando testamos com uma   entrada genérica 'P' pertencente ao intervalo [0, 1), o código não executa :

```
  Traceback (ZeroDivisionError: float modulo)
```

Fiz uma adaptação para uso pessoal e postarei aqui para ajudar outras pessoas:

```
def Arredonda(x):    
    return  0 if not x else (int(x + (1 if int(x) % x == int(x) else 0)))
```

Há uma outra maneira mais simples que descobri enquanto tentava lembrar do código acima:

```
def Arredonda(n):
    return int(n + (0 if n % 1 ==  0 else 1))
```