# Arredondamento para baixo no Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matemática

Estou escrevendo um programa em Python e me surgiu uma dúvida aqui. Antes de vir perguntar eu pesquisei por "Arredondamento Python" aqui no SOpt e encontrei duas perguntas antigas com o assunto, mas ambas não responderam minha dúvida.

Essa pergunta aqui [Como "arredondar" um float em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44715/como-arredondar-um-float-em-python/44718#44718) fala sobre a função `round()` que já conheço, mas ela não me atende, pois a função `round()` trabalha arredondando sempre para o número mais próximo, vejamos os exemplos:

```
a = 5.92
b = round(a,0)
print(b)
```

O resultado mostrado será 6.

```
a = 5.22
b = round(a,0)
print(b)
```

O resultado mostrado será 5. Ou seja, ele só arredonda para baixo se a fração decimal foi abaixo de 0,5.

Também encontrei essa pergunta [Como fazer arredondamento para cima com Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/317381/como-fazer-arredondamento-para-cima-com-python/317383#317383), que aborda a função `ceil`, que faz arredondamentos para cima. Como desejo arredondar para baixo, esta, por óbvio, também não me atende, pois vejamos os exemplos:

```
from math import ceil
a = 5.92
b = ceil(a)
print(b)
```

O resultado mostrado será 6.

```
from math import ceil
a = 5.22
b = ceil(a)
print(b)
```

O resultado mostrado também será 6.

**Que função arredonda para baixo no Python?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A função contrária do `ceil()` (teto) é a função [`floor()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.floor) (chão). Veja a documentação (está na mesma página da `ceil()`.

```
from math import floor
a = 5.92
b = floor(a)
print(b)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/uKqG5N). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/byoduzae-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Math/Floor.py).

Em alguns casos a pessoa pode querer usar a `trunc()`. Em geral as pessoas conceitual errado o arredondamento, e esquecem dos negativos. Com um número positivo as duas resultam igual, mas em números negativos dá resultados diferentes.

Comment: Deu certo aqui, obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Tbm dá pra fazer manualmente, é bem simples, mesmo usando o round, com a condição, ele vai pegar sempre a parte inteira do valor.

```
numero = float(input('Digite um numero real: '))
num = round(numero)
if numero - num < 0:
    num -= 1
print(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

O que você está querendo é calcular o `chão` de um número.

O `chão` de um número `real` (número de ponto flutuante) é o `maior` número inteiro `menor` que o referido número `real`.

Exemplo 01:

O `chão` de `22.6` é `22`

Pois, o `maior` número inteiro `inferior` ao número real de valor `22.6` tem como resultado o valor `22`

Exemplo 02:

O `chão` de `-22.6` é `-23`

Pois, o `maior` número inteiro `inferior` ao número real de valor `-22.6` tem como resultado o valor `-23`.

**Antes de questionar o resultado exibido neste 2º exemplo** deves observa a `direção` na disposição dos valores na reta `real`.

Na reta real os números são distribuídos no sentido da `esquerda` para a `direita`. Em outras palavras, dado um número real `N`, todo número `maior` que `N` será colocado à sua `direita`...

```
22.6, 23.0, 27.0 29.6, 30.4...
```

...todo número `menor` que N será colocado à sua `esquerda`...

```
...16.0, 17.5, 20.0, 22.4, 22.6, 23.0
```

Diante desta explicação podemos agora ver nitidamente o resultado do `2º exemplo`, isto é,

```
-25.0, -24.7, -23.0, -22.6, -22.0,...
```

Ou seja, como o valor `-23` está posicionado à `esquerda` de `-22.6`. isto significa dizer que o `chão` de `-22.6` é o número `-23`.

Para se calcular o `chão` de um número em `Python` é necessário executarmos o método `floor` da classe `math`.

Para mostrar o funcionamento desse método desenvolvi o seguinte algoritmo...

```
from math import floor

lista = [-22.6, 15.3, 16.3, 17.9, 21.4, 22.5, 25.6, 26.9]

resultado = list()
for numero in lista:
    # Calculando os valores dos Tetos de cada valor contido em "lista".
    resultado.append(floor(numero))

print(f'\033[32mOs valores dos Tetos são: {resultado}\033[m')
```

Verifique o funcionamento do algoritmo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/spwfwcpb-solkarped).

Observe que este algoritmo calcula o `chão` de todos os elementos da lista anterior.

Observe também, que o resultado do método `floor` sempre será um valor `inteiro`.

Answer (score 0):

Oi, tudo bem?

Eu fiquei com a mesma dúvida, mas eu resolvi o meu código transformando o resultado float em int, assim ele arredondou pra baixo.

exemplo:

segundos = 140156
minutos = (segundos/60)  # resultado 2.335,933333333333  ---> 2.336 arredondado
horas = (minutos/60) # resultado 38,93222222222222 ---> 39 arredondado

agora, se eu quero arredondar pra baixo, ao invés de usar o round ou os outros métodos, eu posso simplesmente fazer assim:

segundos = 140156
minutos = int(segundos/60)  # resultado 2.335 arredondado pra baixo
horas = int(minutos/60) # resultado 38 arredondado pra baixo