# Arredondamento de float para cima no python 3

Tags: python, float, arredondamento

Como faço um arredondamento para cima no python 3 ? Por exemplo, o cálculo 4000/18 resultar sempre em 223.

Comment: Acho que você pode encontrar a resposta para isso com uma simples pesquisa no Google ou no próprio SO, não? Veja esse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/317381/como-fazer-arredondamento-para-cima-com-python/317383)

Comment: @user140828 quando for assim, pode clicar em "Sinalizar" e colar o link na sessão de duplicata. Ajuda o autor da pergunta e a moderação. Sem falar que já comenta automaticamente com o link da pergunta referenciada.

Answer (score 1):

Para arredondar um número para cima, utilize da biblioteca própria do python math, junto com a função [ceil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil)

```
import math
print(math.ceil(4000/18))
```

Isso irá resultar em 223

Edit: Como nos comentários há um código a mais deveria colocar uma linha a mais como essa, depois de fazer a divisão

```
calculo = math.ceil(calculo)
```

Comment: certo, mas nesse exemplo de código, como eu faço para que o resultado da variável cálculo sempre resulte em um número inteiro para cima, independente dos outros valores?  
custo = float(input("Informe o custo do espetáculo teatral, em reais: "))  
convite = float(input("Informe o valor do convite, em reais: "))  
calculo = custo/convite  
print("Para que não haja prejuízo, devem ser vendidos: ",calculo, "convites")

Comment: irei editra a resposta

Comment: muito obrigado! consegui